# Chromadb + Langchain + SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction throwing 'SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction' object has no attribute 'embed_documents'

Tags: information-retrieval, langchain, sentence-transformers, chromadb

I have been trying to use

- `Chromadb` version `0.4.8`
- `Langchain` version `0.0.276`

with `SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction` as shown in the snippet below.

```
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions

# other imports
embedding = embedding_functions.SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
```

However, it throws the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction' object has no attribute 'embed_documents'
```

Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: you can refer this https://betterprogramming.pub/building-a-question-answer-bot-with-langchain-vicuna-and-sentence-transformers-b7f80428eadc

Answer (score 1):

Your error irrelevant with code that you provided. I am on same versions with you but this works for me, maybe your usage of `embedding` variable can cause this error.

[image]

Can you please provide full code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe just like you used LangChain's wrapper on Chroma, you need to use LangChain's wrapper for SentenceTransformer aswell:

```
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
```

Full guide: https://blog.futuresmart.ai/using-langchain-and-open-source-vector-db-chroma-for-semantic-search-with-openais-llm